# Formula's for Product Notation(Rewriting of Product Form)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find a formula for the sequence $z$ defined by $$z_{y+1}= \prod_{i=1}^y z_i  $$

Can someone show me the steps on how to find this formula?

Answer (score 1):

Consider logs.  $$\begin{align}
\log{z_{y+1}}&=\sum_{i=1}^y\log{z_i} \\
\log{z_{y+1}}-\log{z_y}&=\sum_{i=1}^y\log{z_i}-\sum_{i=1}^{y-1}\log{z_i}=\log{z_y} \\
\log{z_{y+1}}&=2\log{z_y} \\
\log{z_{y+1}}&=2^{y+1}\log z_1 \\
z_{y+1}&=z_1^{2^{y+1}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I dont understand how that makes the formula though? And we haven't discussed logs to use for this? So is there another way? what you have isnt really a formula, could you elaborate please??

Answer (score 1):

The logs place the problem in a relatively-simpler setting, but we can do without them as follows.

$
\;\;\;\;\;\;z_{y+1}
\\
= z_y \times z_{y+1} / z_y
\\
= z_y \times \prod_{i=1}^y z_i / \prod_{i=1}^{y-1} z_i
\\
= z_y \times z_y
\\
= z_y^2
$

Now we *unroll* to obtain
$z_{y+1}=z_y^2 = (z_{y-1}^2)^2 = z_{y-1}^4 = z_{y_2}^8 = \cdots = z_{1}^{2^{y}}$.

But this is not a formal proof; for that we do induction to show: for all $y$, $$z_y = z_1^{2^{y-1}}$$

For the inductive case, $z_{y+1} = z_y^2$ by the above calculation,
and this in-turn, by inductive hypothesis, is equal to $(z_1^{2^{y-1}})^2
= z_1^{2 \times 2^{y-1}} = z_1^{2^{(y+1)-1}}$, as desired.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition, note that $z_2=\prod_{i=1}^1z_i=z_1$. With this result, we have that $z_3=\prod_{i=1}^2z_i=z_1\cdot z_2=z_1^2$ and $z_4=\prod_{i=1}^3z_i=z_1\cdot z_2\cdot z_3=z_1\cdot z_1\cdot z_1^2=z_1^4$.

Noting that $z_{y+1}=z_1^{2^{y-1}}$ for some values $y$, you can use induction on $y$ to prove the general result.

Supose the result is valid to $y=1\ldots n-1$ for some $n-1$, lets check the case $y=n$.

$$z_{y+1}=z_{n+1}=\prod_{i=1}^nz_i=z_n\cdot\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}z_i$$

By the induction hypothesis, we now that $z_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}z_i=z_1^{2^{n-2}}$. Therefore

$$z_{n+1}=z_n\cdot z_n=z_1^{2\cdot2^{n-2}}=z_1^{2^{n-1}}$$
and by the principle of induction the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align*}
  z_2 ~ = ~ & \prod_{k = 1}^1 z_k ~ = ~ z_1 \\
  z_3 ~ = ~ & \prod_{k = 1}^2 z_k ~ = ~ z_1^2 \\
  z_4 ~ = ~ & \prod_{k = 1}^3 z_k ~ = ~ z_1^4 \\
  z_5 ~ = ~ & \prod_{k = 1}^4 z_k ~ = ~ z_1^8 \\
  z_6 ~ = ~ & \prod_{k = 1}^5 z_k ~ = ~ z_1^{16} \\
  \vdots & \quad\quad ~~~~\vdots \\
  z_n ~ = ~ & \prod_{k = 1}^{n - 1} z_k ~ = ~ z_1^{2^{n - 2}}
\end{align*}
$$